# UIView animations prevented after returning from background ios8 (Rubymotion)

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, rubymotion

I'm trying to restart a UIView animation after the user returns to the app from the background.

Here's the animation:

```
  def animate_glow
    UIView.animateWithDuration(GLOW_SPEED,
      delay: 0.0,
      options: UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat |
               UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse |
               UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction,
      animations: -> {
        @swipe_glow.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(GLOW_SCALE, GLOW_SCALE)
      },
      completion: nil
    )
  end
```

Listening for `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` I'm trying to call `animate_glow` but my animations don't restart/are prevented. Logs show that the notification listener is being called and that `UIView.areAnimationsEnabled` returns `true`. I've also tried removing the view referenced by `@swipe_glow` from superview and creating a new one, and calling `animate_glow` This also has no effect on the actual animation (though a new UIView can be created without issue).

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution I found, just in case anyone else finds this problem:

`UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat |
               UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse |`

These lines appeared to be the cause of the problem, as when the animation returned from the background the animations were being set to their end point (`GLOW SCALE`). The system then attempted to restart the animation but found no change to animate.

Two possible solutions: Listen for `UIApplicationDidEnterBackground` and in the handler reset the view to be animate's position back to it's origin.

Or change the animation blocks to animate & reverse methods that call each other in their `completion:` blocks.

Hope this helps someone!